# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Signature MD5WITHRSA implementation not found

Tags: java, cryptography, websphere, bouncycastle

I'm having problems on a Websphere server 8.5
with
Java version = 1.6.0, Java Runtime Version = pap6460_26sr8fp7ifx-20151008_01 (SR8 FP7)

The code that fails is:

```
   Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
   Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA", "BC");
```

The error I get is:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Signature MD5WITHRSA implementation not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi$MD5
```

The same code works on a development environment with a slightly different java version (Java version = 1.6.0, Java Runtime Version = pap6460_26sr8fp20-20160111_01 (SR8 FP20))

I have tried listing all signature algorithm with the following code:

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

```
    TreeSet<String> algorithms = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders())
        for (Service service : provider.getServices())
            if (service.getType().equals("Signature"))
                algorithms.add(service.getAlgorithm());
    for (String algorithm : algorithms)
        System.out.println(algorithm);
```

and I get:

```
DSA
DSAforSSL
ECDSA
ECDSAforSSL
ECGOST3410
GOST3410
GOST3411WITHECGOST3410
MD2WITHRSA
MD2withRSA
MD4WITHRSA
MD5WITHRSA
MD5withRSA
MD5withRSA/ISO9796-2
NONEWITHDSA
NONEwithECDSA
OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.10
RAWRSASSA-PSS
RIPEMD128WITHRSA
RIPEMD160WITHECDSA
RIPEMD160WITHRSA
RIPEMD160withRSA/ISO9796-2
RIPEMD256WITHRSA
RMD128WITHRSA
RMD160WITHRSA
RMD256WITHRSA
RSA
RSAPSS
RSASSA-PSS
RSAforSSL
SHA1WITHCVC-ECDSA
SHA1WITHECNR
SHA1WITHRSA
SHA1withDSA
SHA1withECDSA
SHA1withRSA
SHA1withRSA/ISO9796-2
SHA1withRSA/PSS
SHA224WITHCVC-ECDSA
SHA224WITHDSA
SHA224WITHECDSA
SHA224WITHECNR
SHA224WITHRSA
SHA224withECDSA
SHA224withRSA
SHA224withRSA/PSS
SHA256WITHCVC-ECDSA
SHA256WITHDSA
SHA256WITHECDSA
SHA256WITHECNR
SHA256WITHRSA
SHA256withDSA
SHA256withRSA
SHA256withRSA/PSS
SHA2withECDSA
SHA384WITHDSA
SHA384WITHECDSA
SHA384WITHECNR
SHA384WITHRSA
SHA384withRSA
SHA384withRSA/PSS
SHA3withECDSA
SHA512WITHDSA
SHA512WITHECDSA
SHA512WITHECNR
SHA512WITHRSA
SHA512withRSA
SHA512withRSA/PSS
SHA5withECDSA
```

So, MD5withRSA is there.

Class org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi$MD5 is inside the application and

```
 System.out.println("--->DigestSignatureSpi" + MD5.class.getResource("DigestSignatureSpi$MD5.class"));
```

returns the location of the class correctly.

What could be the problem be then?

Comment: Based on `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` I believe that `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi$MD5` is not in the classpath when you execute `Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA", "BC")`. Have you checked the version of Bouncy Castle in both cases?

Comment: The version is the same as the jar is in the same war of the web application. The file has to be in the classpath. Otherwise System.out.println("--->DigestSignatureSpi" + MD5.class.getResource("DigestSignatureSpi$MD5.class")) wouldn't tell me where it is.

Answer (score 2):

Please verify your output with following snippet.

AlgoCheck.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class AlgoCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchProviderException, ClassNotFoundException {

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
URL bcClassUrl = AlgoCheck.class.getClassLoader()
        .getResource("org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.class");
System.out.println("BouncyCastleProvider class URL   = " + bcClassUrl);

ClassLoader loader = DigestSignatureSpi.MD5.class.getClassLoader();
URL md5ClassUrl = loader.getResource(
 "org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/rsa/DigestSignatureSpi$MD5.class");
System.out.println("DigestSignatureSpi.MD5 class URL = " + md5ClassUrl);

Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA", "BC");
System.out.println("algorithm = " + sign.getAlgorithm());
    }
}
```

The library from which the classes `BouncyCastleProvider` and `DigestSignatureSpi.MD5` are loaded should be the same.

example output

```
BouncyCastleProvider class URL   = jar:file:/home/suboptimal/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.49/bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar!/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.class
DigestSignatureSpi.MD5 class URL = jar:file:/home/suboptimal/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.49/bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar!/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/rsa/DigestSignatureSpi$MD5.class
algorithm = MD5withRSA
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue with harmony. Place a Bouncy jars into the appserver lib/ext directory.